# Memory Management in Django Applications

Tags: django, memory-management

I'm running Django applications on [Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/services/hosting) and [AWS EC2 Micro Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)(613MB of RAM) servers. From past 2-3 months I'm facing memory over limit issues(currently only 4-5 users are using this application). Due to memory over limit, MySQL and APACHE processes are getting killed. I've taken the following steps to reduce memory consumption-

1. Removed ".all()" django queries.
2. Swap space of 1.5 GB.
3. Apache Configuration changed to:

   - StartServers       4
   - MinSpareServers    2
   - MaxSpareServers    4
   - MaxClients         7
   - ServerLimit        7
   - MaxRequestsPerChild    0
4. MySQL -> my.cnf changed to:

   - slow-query-log=1
   - max_connections=45
   - query_cache_size=16M
   - table_cache=128
   - tmp_table_size=32M
   - max_heap_table_size=33554432
5. Installed "Dozer" to find memory leaks(Not reporting any problem).

Somebody please let me know, what else can be done to reduce memory consumption.
Also let me know, how can I track the time, taken by a django filter query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more thing, As you said "Not to sort or iterate through a long queryset". How can I break a long queryset into batches to iterate or to sort?

Comment: Where is your memory being used? What does "ps x -o rss,comm" look like?

Comment: Have you tried using Nginx and gevent? Depending on your use-case you could get more performance out of a smaller memory footprint. Not sure what you are allowed to do on AWS, but on Webfaction it is pretty easy to hook up your own instance of Nginx to one or more WSGI-servers running for example Gunicorn in gevent mode. You only need two worker processes if your workload is greenlet friendly (not blocking).

Comment: If you are really strapped for memory it is even possible to get the WSGI-server down to one process while still performing VERY well (on non-blocking greenlet-friendly workloads), but you lose graceful server restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already use `django-debug-toolbar`? It helps you with tracking long or unwanted queries – this is for local environment.

For hosted application, make sure you have `DEBUG` set to `False`. Django keeps track of all queries for infinity when debug mode is enabled.

If it doesn't help search for global/class attributes that holds big data structures and move those to cache/db.

Also make sure not to sort long lists in your views/forms or iterate through very long querysets as all goes to memory at instance. Try to do it in small batches instead.